# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException : The application must supply JDBC connections

Tags: java, hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name ="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name ="conection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeesdb</property>
<property name ="connection.username">root</property>
<property name ="connection.password">password@123</property>

<property name ="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name ="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<mapping class = "com.start.Student"></mapping>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Normally I should be able to connect to DB but I am getting an error.
Error: - "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections"

It means I am not able to connect with DB.
I have checked that the database username and password are correct.
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29eOg.png)
[Main Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjg1z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in `conection.url`. Should be `connection.url`.

Comment: Ohh!! Thank You so much, friend. I have been trying to find out for 2 days. Such a horrible mistake I have done.